# Compiling C with MS Visual C++ 2010 'sys/resource.h': No such file

Tags: c++, c, matlab, visual-c++, mex

I'm trying to MEX (compile) the implementation linked as "Metric WFG implementation" on http://www.wfg.csse.uwa.edu.au/hypervolume/

When doing so with the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 compiler, I received errors about sys/time.h and stdbool.h.

I created my own stdbool.h with the following:

```
#pragma once

#define false   0
#define true    1

#define bool int
```

and checked sys/time.h to time.h.

However I'm now stuck with the following issue:

```
wfg.c(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/resource.h': No such file or directory
```

I tried removing sys/ however it gives the same error.

Anyone know the solution?

Thank you

Comment: the use of `sys/time.h` and `sys/resource.h` seems to be limited to the main program `wfg.c` to measure time and resource usage. You could probably comment out those parts and try to compile again... That said I dont see how that is related to MATLAB so far

Comment: Hi Amro, this is Matlab related because I'm trying to MEX it to use under Matlab. Your idea of removing the resource usage stuff was good, I tried it, however it didn't work, or I'm not experienced enough to know what to remove, any ideas?

Comment: this project is clearly written with GCC as compiler in mind. Apart from commenting the POSIX stuff mentioned before, you'll also have to move all local variable declarations to the beginning of each function (MSVC C compiler only supports C89, so it wont accept declarations like: `for (int i;;)`). In fact, the Makefile invokes `gcc -std=C99`, which MSVC is known not to fully support. Once you have made those changes, I think you'll manage to compile it... As a last step, try renaming all files as `.cpp` to compile as C++ rather than C, this will probably give you much less compilation errors

Comment: Amro, thank you for your reply. I will try all your suggestions tomorrow, I am not a C/C++ dev so this kind of stuff is difficult for me, specially when it's someone else's code.

Answer (score 5):

sys/resource.h is a posix header file, of course the VC2010 can't find it. Maybe you should install cygwin to do this work if you stick to windows.

Comment: Hi, it's Matlab I'm stuck with. Is there any way to get a Windows compiler or to get the resource.h file to put in the same directory?

Comment: That's like saying "I need a brain surgeon but I only have a general practitioner available. Is there a way I can put a fake diploma on his office wall so he can operate on my brain?" Normally, header files are declarations of interfaces, not implementations. Dropping in a header declaring interfaces that have no implementation available on your system is not going to magically implement them.

Comment: @Derek No way. You can get cygwin to do it or get a linux OS.