# Python. sys/resource.h: No such file or directory error while building whl

Tags: python, pip, build-tools

I try to install Python package [hdt](https://pypi.org/project/hdt/) on Windows 10. I need hdt because it is a dependency of a big package I need.
There is a c++ error while building whl on Windows. Building of whl starts after command `pip install hdt`.
The error is:

```
cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9002: Їа®ЇгбЄ ­ҐЁ§ўҐбв­®Ј® Ї а ¬Ґва  "-std=c++11"
BitSequence.cpp
hdt-cpp-1.3.3/libcds/include/libcdsBasics.h(27): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory,
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

There are setuptools updated.
There are MS Build Tools installed as it said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575792/10963649
I tried it on Linux and I've installed hdt easily on Linux but I don't want to change the platform because of problems with one package.
Some questions you could help me with:

1. Is it possible that whl could be built only on Linux?
2. My MS VS is x86 as I see in error (C:\Program Files (x86)\...). Shalln't I choose x86 versions of MS BuiltTools components?
3. There is a warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'. What should be done (installed) to prevent it?
4. The final error is C1083 Cannot open include file: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory. Could it be caused by the lack of MS Built Tools components? It looks strange though

Any other ideas how to build whl for hdt?
Maybe as a workaround it could be considered: as there is hdt installed on Linux maybe it's possible to build a whl on Linux and then copy on Windows. But there is .so file on Linux and I'm not sure it's possible to add .so in whl and then install it on Windows.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18671155/5666087, `sys/resource.h` is a POSIX header file and will not be found in Windows, unless you use Cygwin.